# Need to sort a list alphabetically

Tags: c#, list, sorting

I need to sort out the following list alphabetically increasing order.

```
IList<KeyValuePair<long, string>> myList = new List<KeyValuePair<long, string>>()
```

The list is getting populated after making DB call.

```
myList = DataAdapter.GetTemplates().ToList();
```

Tried method:

```
myList = myList.OrderBy(x => x.Value,StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase).ToList();
```

However, this doesn't seem to be working correctly.
Before sorting:

```
Assessment1
Assessment2
Assess5
Assess7
Toxic Only
Perform Only
Question only
```

After sorting:

```
Assess5
Assess7 
Assessment1
Assessment2
Perform Only
Question only
Toxic Only
```

Comment: Although you already have an answer to your question, you should have provided more information regarding your problem:

- Should the list be sorted by Key or Value?
- Should the first index be popped out before sorting or after?

Also it would be nice to add an example of what you've tried to far, instead of just asking for the answer. You can check question guidelines [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I provided what my problem is. Could you be more specific pls?

Comment: @Grazina Clearly it wouldn't be by key considering the key is numeric.

Comment: @Llama you're correct, I was just pointing out that questions should be explicit and include at least one attempt to resolve the problem.

Comment: @Grazina You're not wrong there :)

Comment: If you just have a `List<T>` you can use [an overload of `List<T>.Sort()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.sort?view=net-5.0#System_Collections_Generic_List_1_Sort_System_Int32_System_Int32_System_Collections_Generic_IComparer__0__) that allows you to specify the range of elements to sort.

Comment: Whatever i tried, details edited

Comment: Re your edit: please show the code to initialize the list with these test values. It's not clear what text belongs with what entry.

Comment: Pls see my edits

Comment: I notice you've edited your question to no longer require excluding the first item from the sorting. I'm voting to close this question until a time when you can clarify what you actually want. Examples are good for this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Note** This answer was posted before OP changed their question. Originally OP wanted to sort all of the items except the first one. [Original revision](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/68663781/1)

---

You could do this using LINQ:

```
myList = myList
    .Take(1) // take the first item from the list
    .Concat( // concatenate the following subquery
        myList
            .Skip(1) // take all elements after the first one
            .OrderBy(kv => kv.Value, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase) // sort by the value ignoring the case
    )
    .ToList(); // materialise the query to a list
```

The current comparer is case insensitive, but you can [choose an appropriate one](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.stringcomparer?view=net-5.0#properties) for your use case.

The result for your sample input is as follows:

```
Assessment1
Assess5
Assess7
Assessment2
Perform Only
Question only
Toxic Only
```

[Try it online](https://rextester.com/MPV83616)

Comment: @Sandy So you tried a different solution to the answer I provided and that different solution didn't work? Why not try my solution?

Comment: @sandy [try it online](https://rextester.com/XXAR36394) - what's wrong with the result? If this differs from your expected output, then you should edit your question to state what you expect the output to be, because if it's not this then you clearly don't want alphabetical order, despite what you've stated.

Answer (score 1):

you can use bubble sort, just start the second loop from 1

```
for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++)
            for (int j = 1; j < n - i - 1; j++)
                if (arr[j] > arr[j + 1])
                {
                    int temp = arr[j];
                    arr[j] = arr[j + 1];
                    arr[j + 1] = temp;
                }
    }
```

as shown above, 2nd loop is started with 1, so it will exclude element at the 0th index